# How to extract initials from a name using Laravel

Tags: string, laravel

I have the method below that returns me a list of registered users:

```
$users = \App\Models\User::all();
```

It turns out that I would like to present only the initials of the names on that list.

Example:

Carlos Pereira do Nascimento = **CN**

Marcos Aurelio = **MA**

Sandra Lopes = **SL**

How could I do this by getting this data from the list?

Is it possible for me to treat this list by taking only the initials of the variable $ name?

Comment: If initials are stored in Users then you can do: `\App\Models\User::select('initials')->get()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```php
$names = \App\Models\User::pluck('name');
$initials = [];
foreach($names as $name) {
    $nameParts = explode(' ', trim($name));
    $firstName = array_shift($nameParts);
    $lastName = array_pop($nameParts);
    $initials[$name] = (
        mb_substr($firstName,0,1) .
        mb_substr($lastName,0,1)
    );
}

var_dump($initials);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Carlos Pereira do Nascimento"]=>
  string(2) "CN"
  ["Marcos Aurelio"]=>
  string(2) "MA"
  ["Émile Durkheim"]=>
  string(2) "ÉD"
}
```

Note the use of mb_substr as opposed to regular substr or a string index. This will return correct values for names starting with non ASCII characters like for example "Émile"

```php
echo substr('Émile Durkheim', 0, 1);
// output: b"Ã"
echo 'Émile Durkheim'[0];
// output: b"Ã"
echo mb_substr('Émile Durkheim', 0, 1);
// output: É
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Laravel's accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to get the initials modifying the following code:

```
public function getInitialsAttribute(){
    $name = 'Carlos Pereira do Nascimento';
    $name_array = explode(' ',trim($name));

    $firstWord = $name_array[0];
    $lastWord = $name_array[count($name_array)-1];

    return $firstWord[0]."".$lastWord[0];
}
```

Now, you can get the initals using `{{ $user->initials }}`

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a simple, one-line, framework-agnostic solution:

```
$initials = preg_filter('/[^A-Z]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: This returns all capital letters. "Test User" would return "TU" while "Another great Test User" would return "ATU".  That might be sufficient for some use cases.

Answer (score 3):

I have just made the following PR to introduce a new `Str::initials()` String helper function in Laravel framework: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40381

For those who already want to use this before it's accepted/merged, just extend `Illuminate\Support\Str` with this macro in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method:

```php
        Str::macro('initials', fn($value, $sep = ' ', $glue = ' ') => trim(collect(explode($sep, $value))->map(function ($segment) {
            return $segment[0] ?? '';
        })->join($glue)));
```

and then just use `Str::initials('Foo Bar')` or as an Eloquent accessor in your `User` model:

```php
    public function getInitialsAttribute(): string
    {
        return \Illuminate\Support\Str::initials($this->name);
    }
```

so you can simply use something like `{{ Auth::user()->initials }}`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Put this 2 line code**

```
    function initials($str) {
         $ret = '';
         foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $word)
           $ret .= strtoupper($word[0]);
         return $ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to expand the answers above to help others looking to do the same.

Here's an example on what I did.

Create an Accessor in your user model:

```
public function getNameInitials()
{
    $name = $this->name;
    $name_array = explode(' ',trim($name));

    $firstWord = $name_array[0];
    $lastWord = $name_array[count($name_array)-1];

    return mb_substr($firstWord[0],0,1)."".mb_substr($lastWord[0],0,1);
}
```

Then you can access it in your view as `{{ $user->getNameInitials() }}`
or you could easily access the initials of the authenticated user as follows `{{ Auth::user()->getNameInitials() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Today in 2023, the most elegant way would be using Laravel's Fluent String helper:

```php
Str::of('John Doe Smith')
    ->explode(' ') // Split the name into parts
    ->map(fn($part) => Str::of($part)->substr(0, 1)->upper()) // Take the first letter and uppercase it
    ->join(''); // Join the initials together
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/auth-username-intials-in-blade-template) solution on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com) and I found it worked excellently for me.

Simply create an `initials()` function in your user model

```
public function initials(){
    $words = explode(" ", $this->name );
    $initials = null;
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        $initials .= $w[0];
    }
    return strtoupper($initials);
 }
```

Then simply call your initials() function in your blade view: `{{ Auth::user()->initials() }}` instead of `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`